# Write a test class for dynamically created custom fields

Tags: apex, code-coverage

I have a code whose logic revolves around the availability of certain fields on the org. I am checking this with

```
if(Schema.SObjectType.CustomObject__c.fields.getMap().keySet().contains('customField__c'))
```

There is no else to it if those fields are not present, then the code skips everything and nothing gets executed. Also if no fields are available then the custom message is shown in the app (in Aura).
I am not 100% sure but similar to temporary records in test classes (which get rolled back once the test is finished), we cannot create a custom field that can get deleted/rolled back. (please correct me if I am wrong).

So in this case, how can I write a test class to make sure that I get more coverage on that method? (my current coverage is very low due to the above logic)

Comment: the general solution to this problem is to use dependency injection - move the describe into a separate object and at testmethod time, inject a mock object that returns false/true so you can test your logic. Similar concept to HttpCalloutMock

Comment: you can also generalize the describe to accept a sobjectType as argument and for testmethods, use an sobjectType with a field that is unavailable unless some feature you know will never be activated enables that field